# Problema al recorrer diccionario en Python

Tags: python, bucle-for

me surge una duda,  a la hora de recorrer un diccionario con un for y otro diccionario con otro for dentro del primero un valor no lo toma y me gustaria saber porque es:

CODIGO:

```
print("lc" ,lista_compras)
print("lv" ,lista_ventas)
for producto_compra in lista_compras:
    clave=producto_compra
    valor=lista_compras.get(producto_compra)
    for producto_venta in lista_ventas:
        clave2=producto_venta
        valor2=lista_ventas.get(producto_venta)
    print("LISTA COMPRAS:" ,clave,"value;" ,valor)
    print("LISTA VENTAS:" ,clave2,"value2;" ,valor2)
```

Y los valores que me arroja son:

```
lc {'baaa': {4161.6}, 'aaaa': {2874.36}}
lv {'aaaa': {36271.2}, 'baaa': {25395.370000000003}}
LISTA COMPRAS: baaa value; {4161.6}
LISTA VENTAS: baaa value2; {25395.370000000003}
LISTA COMPRAS: aaaa value; {2874.36}
LISTA VENTAS: baaa value2; {25395.370000000003}
```

¿Por que cuando recorro compras me toma los dos elementos y en ventas no?
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que imprimes es el valor que ha quedado en las variables `clave2` y `valor2` una vez has salido del bucle interno. Ese bucle sobreescribe las mismas variables en cada iteración por lo que al salir sólo tienes el último valor. Supongo que el `print()` debería estar dentro de ese bucle.

Por otro lado el bucle interno no debería ser interno, pues vuelves a ejecutar el bucle interno completo por cada iteración del bucle externo, y entiendo que no es eso lo que quieres.

De modo que creo que lo que pretendías es esto otro:

```
print("lc" ,lista_compras)
print("lv" ,lista_ventas)
for producto_compra in lista_compras:
    clave=producto_compra
    valor=lista_compras.get(producto_compra)
    print("LISTA COMPRAS:" ,clave,"value;" ,valor)

for producto_venta in lista_ventas:
    clave2=producto_venta
    valor2=lista_ventas.get(producto_venta)
    print("LISTA VENTAS:" ,clave2,"value2;" ,valor2)
```

---

```
lc {'baaa': {4161.6}, 'aaaa': {2874.36}}
lv {'aaaa': {36271.2}, 'baaa': {25395.370000000003}}
LISTA COMPRAS: baaa value; {4161.6}
LISTA COMPRAS: aaaa value; {2874.36}
LISTA VENTAS: aaaa value2; {36271.2}
LISTA VENTAS: baaa value2; {25395.370000000003}
```

También tengo que decir que si todo lo que querías era imprimir los valores del diccionario, el código se podía abreviar a:

```
for clave, valor in lista_compras.items():
    print("LISTA COMPRAS:" ,clave,"value;" ,valor)

for clave, valor in lista_ventas.items():
    print("LISTA VENTAS:" ,clave,"value2;" ,valor)
```

Otra cosa más que me ha llamado la atención es que los valores de tu diccionario los has puesto entre llaves, lo que hace que para python sean conjuntos. Eso es bastante raro... ¿No deberían ser simplemente números, es decir, sin las llaves? Así:

```
lista_compras = {'baaa': 4161.6, 'aaaa': 2874.36 }
```